# Program Errors in VERY Specific Instance - Detailed

Tags: python

I've written a simple console program in Python to perform basic logical calculations. However, when I use any of the single letters r,s,t or u (lower case) as variables, the console simply stalls. It doesn't produce an error or anything, and I end up having to Ctrl+C (Keyboard Interrupt in Linux). However, using any other letters in the alphabet aside from these four, my program runs fine.

Here is a snip of the exact moment where the console stalls:

[image: When the Console Stalls]

And another snip of right after I Keyboard Interrupt after a stall, and a successful run of the program:

[image: After a Keyboard Interrupt Following a Stall]

[image: Successful Run of the Program]

Here is the code segment referenced when I use a Keyboard Interrupt:

```
# Since my userExpression string is going
# to have a variable length, I had to 
# initialize another variable to keep
# up with it and make sure that the while
# loop runs until the updated string ends.

truthList = truthMachine(propNum)
exprLength = len(userExpression)
while whileCounter < exprLength:
    if userExpression[whileCounter] in varDict:
        userExpression =  userExpression.replace(userExpression[whileCounter],"truthList[i][" + str(varDict[userExpression[whileCounter]]) + "]")
    exprLength = len(userExpression)
    whileCounter += 1
```

This portion of the program is just supposed to switch the lower case letter variable with its value in a dictionary that I created. Again, it works with any other letter in the alphabet and I've thoroughly tested more complicated logical propositions and they all work if I'm not using r,s,t or u. Hopefully someone here has seen something similar.

Comment: I'm sure either that this error is obvious to the not so tired eye, but if it isn't this problem probably resides in one of the functions you are calling. I suggest you do `python -m trace --trace script.py` and start diggin : )

Comment: I suspect your while loop ends up being infinite, as `truthList[i][` is continually inserted into `userExpression`, thus its length keeps growing and you never reach the end of it.  (The letters "rstu" are all present in "truthList".)

Comment: That makes a ton of sense. I just ran the trace and got a ton of gibberish I don't understand, so I'll look at this and try to make some modifications. Thank you!

Comment: Changed the name of truthList and it works now! Thanks again!